# How make the relationship splitting the score of soccer in cypher

Tags: database-design, neo4j, cypher

In EPL match, the results between two teams is 2-6, so how to make the relationship
and show that the high goals scored team won the match.

Here is an attempt to load the CSV data.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///EPL_dataset_for_2018_19_assignment.csv" as row
MERGE (team1:EPL_Teams{name:row.Team1})
MERGE (team2:EPL_Teams{name:row.Team2})
MERGE (round:Round{name:row.Round})
MERGE (date:Date{name:row.Date})
MERGE (score1:Scores{name:row.HT})
MERGE (score2:Scores{name:row.FT})
```

Comment: I think you have a real question, but there is no way for anyone to help without more information.  What nodes do you have? ... relationships? ... labels? ... properties?  Have you tried something that didn't work?

Comment: LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///EPL_dataset_for_2018_19_assignment.csv" as row
MERGE (team1:EPL_Teams{name:row.Team1})
MERGE (team2:EPL_Teams{name:row.Team2})
MERGE (round:Round{name:row.Round})
MERGE (date:Date{name:row.Date})
MERGE (score1:Scores{name:row.HT})
MERGE (score2:Scores{name:row.FT}) but i have the score in 2-0 format so i want to split score as home and away goal to know which team win or lose

Comment: It's better if you edit your original post to include more information. You can better format code snippets there, etc., and it's easier for readers to find all the relevant info. So, what exactly is in each column of the CSV file? After your data is imported, what sort of queries do you want to make?

Comment: Looking at your node creation, I'm wondering if there is a better way to create nodes and relationships so that answering questions about the matches is easier.

Comment: FYI, this [Neo4j NHL Team Ranking GraphGist](https://neo4j.com/graphgist/nhl-team-ranking-model-using-the-stattleship-sports-api-and-neo4j) might be helpful to see a way to model your data.

Answer (score 1):

You can try data model something like this: 
(Tool to create the model: http://www.apcjones.com/arrows/)

[image]

This is just a hint, I stored score in the relationship if you need you can create a Score node and save the score and outcome in it and then connect this node to Match/Game and Team.

To get the score from string 2-6, you can split these values using the split function like this:

> `split(row.HT, "-") AS scores`

This will create an array of length 2. 
You can easily get these values into variables or properties like:

> ```
> scores[0] as team1_score, scores[1] as team2_score
> ```

Comment: This is for reference, please choose the model which suits best for your use case.

Comment: how to compare the splited score and declare the most wining teams

Comment: As shown above, you can get the results in variables team1_score and team2_score, by default the type is the string, you can convert to an integer by using toInt(team1_score) or toInteger(team1_score) and then compare.

Comment: Thank you for answer, also please help me to find out which teams most win in EPL matches

Comment: What's your current status? What's you have tried and what are you facing issue with?